# Ant-Design form validate returns old values while using onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using ant-design Form Item like this:

```
 {getFieldDecorator('city', {initialValue:'a', rules: [{required:true,message:' '}]})(
     <select onChange={onChange}  className="form-control">
     <option  value='a' >a</option>
     <option  value='b' >b</option>
     </select>
                            }



and here is my onchange function:




onChange=()=>{
 form.validateFields((err, values) => {
            console.log(values)



        })
}
```

The problem is that while changing value to 'b', I still get 'a' as the form value in onChange function (console.log(values)). This happens while changing value from 'b' to 'a' too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up immediate onChange behaviour with validation. If you are looking for a dropdown with immediate action you do not need a `<Form>`, just use the `<Select>` by itself.

If you want a proper form with a submit function, you should **not** use `onChange` on the `<Select>` at all, that is handled automatically by antd. And then you will have proper values when you call `form.validateFields` at form submit time.

Finally, if you **do** want immediate actions using field validation inside a `<Form>`, use the `onFieldsChange` option rather than individual widget `onChange`.

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue. How can I validate the form only when the selection change (onChange)